# allow php to run ln command

Tags: php, bash, nginx, sudo

I've been able to get php user www-data to run git commands via visudo but I keep getting Permission Denied when I want it to run

```
ln -sf target link
```

What should I put in visudo in order for this to run fine?

Answer (score 3):

check if both "target" and "link" are www-data acessible,
 adding privileges in sudores file using visudo allow you to only run commands like

```
sudo powerfullCommand params
```

and not

```
powerfullCommand params
```

to dismiss password request on certain command try

```
some_user ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/ln
```

Hope this can help

take a look to a similar post:

[How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo)