# PHP interface for kernel's IP routing tables operation not permitted

Tags: php, shell, unix, exec, routes

I'm trying to execute route add command with PHP this way:
`exec("/sbin/route -net 127.0.0.1", $output);` and I'm getting `SIOCADDRT operation not permitted`. I suppose this is because I don't execute the route command through `sudo`. 
But I can't do sudo from php because the command asks for the su password. So how can I run route add without sudo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is, IMHO, is to create a shell script which use this command. After that, allow this shell script to be executed as root in `/etc/sudoers`.

The syntax to add in sudoers file can be found in [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo).

So you just need to:

```
exec("/usr/bin/sudo /path/to/script");
```

This way, your root password is not exposed and you can add any command you'd like in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can send set sudo to get password from standard input using -S argument

```
exec("echo 'password' | sudo -u root -S /sbin/route -net 127.0.0.1", $output);
```