# Run SUDO through PHP exec?

Tags: php, python, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo)

I have a Python file that needs SU rights to run (on Ubuntu server).
Can't figure out how to do it.

Running it from PHP like so:

```
$command = "python /path/to/my/file.py params";
$temp = exec($command, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Not working. (Xvfb fails to start for non-root)

Tried:

```
$command = "echo 'root_pwd' | sudo -S python /program.py params"
...
```

didn't work.

Tried: edit /etc/sudoers:

```
Cmnd_Alias BUNDLE = /path/to/myprog.py
nobody  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:BUNDLE
```

and then:

```
$command = "sudo -u nobody python myprog.py params";
...
```

didn't work.
When I say "didn't work" - I mean that var_dump($output) returns empty array, no successful result on server (myprog.py should generate a file on the server) or the page simply loads for a couple mins until it times out.

Basic .py files (that don't require special rights) work.

Pls help.

PS: 
.Py file is making screenshot of URL, so is using webkitgtk, Xvfb and couple other things.

Comment: Many (most?) sudo configurations include the `requiretty` directive which prevent `sudo` from being called by a non-user-terminal process. You might have better luck with `requiretty` disabled, but I highly recommend consulting serverfault.com for the right way to set this up.  You could _severely_ damage your system's security...

Answer (score 0):

Your command is wong:

```
$command = "sudo -u nobody python myprog.py params";
```

Here you're calling the python interpreter directly, but in your `sudores` file you only allowed `/path/to/myprog.py`.

If you want to do it this way, then add a shebang to your python program and make it executable, then change your command to

```
$command = "sudo -u nobody /path/to/myprog.py params";
```

But for this to work, the user you specify in your sudoers file must be the user executing the command, which probably isn't `nobody` but the web server process (`www-data`?):

```
Cmnd_Alias BUNDLE = /path/to/myprog.py
www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:BUNDLE
```

---

The other way you tried

```
$command = "echo 'root_pwd' | sudo -S python /program.py"
```

probably failed because of two reasons:

- the current user (probably the webserver process) isn't allowed to sudo
- `sudo` doesn't take the root password, but the current users password

And you don't really want to pass passwords like this anyway...