# avoid password prompt

Tags: php, unix

I want execute command `sudo ls -l` without password prompt.

```
$streams = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr
);
$process = proc_open('sudo ls -l', $streams, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    list($stdin, $stdout) = $pipes;
    fwrite($stdin, "password\n"); //must write password, but not
    fclose($stdin);
    var_dump(stream_get_contents($stdout));
    fclose($stdout);
    $returnCode = proc_close($process);
    echo "Return code $returnCode\n";
}
```

After execution password prompt still exists, how to avoid it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo

Comment: Unfortunately no, sudo is just example, I need connect to tool which require password

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the command ls to `/etc/sudoers` file ?
you can autorize to a user to execute some command without password.

```
user ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/ls
```