# running shell command from php with sudo

Tags: php, shell, sudo

I want to run this code from php

```
echo <password> | sudo -S /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "dongle show devices"
```

but it's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: is your php_user(apache?) in the sudo-ers file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid before posting you may search all over the possible ways

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the 'backtick' character (`) around your shell string like:

```
<?php
    $output = `command_goes_here`;
    echo $output;
?>
```

Keep in mind this will only work if the shell_exec() function would work on that server, which could also be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Use php function shell_exec  or exec to execute shell commands

For more details

http://www.php.net/shell_exec

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

u can try by this if u want to run shell script command in php file

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

u can also try other way by create .sh file for shell script and run that .sh file by php function

```
$output = shell_exec('./deploy.sh');
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```