# Kill a process from website

Tags: php, linux, centos, kill-process, su

I have the code and everything which is:

```
     pkill python
```

However I wanted to run it from a php script like this:

```
  echo shell_exec("pkill python");
```

I get an output which says:

```
bash: pkill: (1503) - Operation not permitted
```

I know what the problem is, which is that pkill is su command. Anyway to change this so that the php script can run it?

Comment: You should give the Apache user more rights, so it can execute the command.

Comment: You'll find a very nice answer on the [ask ubuntu forums](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password)

Comment: Maybe this link will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that the process you want to kill does not belong to the apache user (apache usually runs as `www-data` with group `www-data`). If you give apache more rights (say run it as user `root`), your PHP script would run with more rights and could do things like this. But this would be dangerous, because if there is a security flaw in apache or your php script, a malicious attacker could take over your system.

Instead I suggest using the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit.

1. Create a file `kill.sh` with the content `pkill python`
2. Make it executable (`chmod a+x kill.sh`)
3. Make it belong to root (`chown root:root kill.sh`)
4. Make it setuid (`chmod u+s kill.sh`)
5. Invoke this script from your php script

Comment: hey i tried doing this (and many other suggestions online) for the past 6 hours and still this doesnt work. any idea? same "pkill: killing pid 25782 failed: Operation not permitted"