# PHP Exec Sudo/Exim commands

Tags: php, linux, shell

I'm trying to get a sudo command to execute from within PHP.  For simplicity sake, I'm using passthru wrapped in pre tags.  Long story short, I want to get some exim stats.

I'm on a CentOS box.

After logging in via shell, I added the following line via visudo.

```
myuser      ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/exiwhat
```

I can successfully execute the exiwhat command using either of the following commands when shelled in.

```
sudo -u myuser -H /usr/sbin/exiwhat
sudo -u myuser -H exiwhat
```

I've even tried becoming the the user via su and am still successful.

```
su myuser
sudo /usr/sbin/exiwhat
-or-
sudo exiwhat
```

My php script looks a little something like this.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
passthru('whoami');
echo "\n1)";
passthru('sudo exiwhat');
echo "\n2)";
passthru('sudo /usr/sbin/exiwhat');
echo "\n3)";
passthru('exiwhat');
echo "\n4)";
passthru('/usr/sbin/exiwhat');
echo "\n";
echo '</pre>';
```

All I get back is:

```
myuser

1)
2)
3)
4)No exim process data
```

I've tried the same with

```
exec('exiwhat',$output);
```

but output returns as an empty array.

I can get simple things like "ps aux" or "dir" to work just fine.  Please help.

Possible Duplicate: [How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo)

Note: I can run exiwhat via command line and get a good chunk of output.  We have several hundred emails in the queue at any point in time.

UPDATE: 
Per another thread, I added " 2>&1" to each command and got the following

```
myuser

1)sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

2)sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

3)sh: exiwhat: command not found

4)/bin/rm: cannot remove `/var/spool/exim/exim-process.info': Permission denied
exim(770): Operation not permitted
exim(8016): Operation not permitted
exim(15618): Operation not permitted
exim(15626): Operation not permitted
exim(16751): Operation not permitted
exim(16765): Operation not permitted
exim(32207): Operation not permitted
exim: no process killed
No exim process data
```

UPDATE: 
I added the following line via visudo and my sudo commands now work

```
Defaults:myuser !requiretty
```

Is that save to leave like that though?

Comment: Further note: Running mod_suphp, so each process should run as its respective user, hopefully as indicated by the whoami command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your /etc/sudoers file and remove the line about Default requiretty.

**Update I guess this options enabled by default so add something like the following instead:

```
Defaults:myuser        !requiretty
```

Comment: Found that over at the following link and got it in just before you posted. http://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user