# Intricacies of Launching a complex shell script from CGI

Tags: linux, apache, bash, shell, fastcgi

Ok, so over the past year I have built some rather complex automation scripts (mostly bash, but with some perl here and there) for some of the more common work we do at my place of business. They rely heavily on ImageMagick, Ghostscript, and PhantomJS to name just a few. They also traverse a huge number of directories across the network and several different file systems and host OSs... Frankly the fact that they work is a bit of a miracle and perhaps a testament to my willingness to keep beating my head against the wall... Also, trust me, this is easier and more effective than trying to corral my resources. Our archives are... organic... and certain high-ranking individuals in the company think of them as belonging to them and do not look out for the interests of the company in their management. They are, at least, relatively well backed-up these days.

In any case these scripts automate the production of a number of image-based print-ready products of varying degrees of complexity up to multi-hundred page image-heavy books, and as such some of them accept absurdly complex argument structures to do all the things they do. (P.S. embedded Javascript in SVGS is a MAGICAL thing!) These systems have been in "working beta" for a while now, which basically means I've been hand entering the commands at a terminal to run them, and I want to move them up to production and offer them as a webservice so that those in production who are not friends with the command line can use them, and to also potentially integrate them with our new custom-developed order management system.

**TL;DR below**

so that's the background, the problem is this:

I'm running everything on a headless CentOS 6.4 virtual machine with SELINUX disabled.
Apache2 serves up my `interface.sh` CGI just fine, and the internet has already helped me make the POST data into shell variables. Now I need to launch the worker scripts that actually direct the heavy lifting and coordinate the binaries... from the CGI:

```
#get post data from form and make it into variables...
/bin/bash /path/to/script/worker.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg5 $arg6 $opt1 $arg7
```

Nothing.

httpd log shows permission denied, fair enough!

Ok, googling suggests that the script being called by the CGI must also be owned by the apache user and group, or by root with 755 permissions. Done!

now httpd log show permission denied for things `worker.sh` is trying to do :/

Google has lead me to believe that for security reasons fcgi requires that everything interacted with by the CGI process chain must have correctly controlled permissions, all the way down to the binaries and source files... Sure, this is smart for security and damage control, but almost impossible in my case. We have very dynamic data and terabytes of resources... :/

the script `worker.sh` exports its own environment and runs all it's commands as root. This is largely to overcome the minefield of permissions disasters that I have to contend with and CentOS's own paranoia about allowing stuff to happen. I had hoped this might be a work around, but no.

One suggestion I have seen is to simply write out the composed command to a text file and have cron or incron do something with the text file. Seems like that would work... BUT, I'd love to be able to get STDIO back into my web page as there are verbose errors and notifications (though no interaction) in many of these worker scripts, and I would like to provide notification of completion as well. Is there any way to do this that doesn't require a permissions war to be waged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run certain commands as another user, you can use `sudo`.

[Set up sudo to allow passwordless access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo) to run your command by the apache user. Then you can have the CGI script call `sudo /path/to/script args` to run it as root (or `-u` for another user of your choice).

It's very hard to make this secure, so you should make sure your CGI script is only accessible by trustworthy individuals.

Comment: Ah! of course, now why didn't I think of that... I had to do that in some of the scripts initially, but I threw security, caution and editing 'sudoers' out the window by just rebuilding the environment, which works fine until well considered security policies intervene ;)

Comment: A note: You will have to comment out "Default requiretty" in sudoers in order for CGI to run sudo. I certainly see that this opens up a whole raft of security issues and in case anyone is reading this I highly don't reccomend this unless you have trusted users and are only working on a secure local netowork (I do and I am). The real solution to this is to have sane security policies in place from the beginning... *sigh*

Comment: and change the apache user's shell to something other than /bin/nologin It works now though :)