# Execute Script as another user whilst not being root

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication

**Situation:**

I'd like to execute a shellscript directly from a web-gui. The shellscript belongs to the user "tux".
Since my webserver is running as apache, I can't execute tux's shellscript.
OS: CENTOS

**What I've tried:**

```
su -c "/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh" -s /bin/sh tux
```

I tried different ways, the mentioned one is how it worked when i was logged in as root user.

**Question:**

Is there a way to do the same while not being root? Something like a command where I can pass the user AND its password to execute the script.

I can't just change the ownership of the script because it's depending on tux's profile (other files, directories).

Thanks very very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "$pass" | sudo -S -u $user script
```

`$pass` is you password, `$user` is the user who wants to run the script. (This user must have permission to run the script.)

If your `user` doesn't have permission, then try running as group:

```
echo "$pass" | sudo -S -g $group script
```

This group must have permission to run the script.

Note: Passing password like this isn't a good idea.

> If your user can't use sudo:

If your user can't use sudo then you can't run the script by switching users with sudo. You should consider executing the script with this non-sudo user account. And for that, this user must have permission to execute the script.

***One way to do that is to change permission of the script to `755` (from sudo user):***

Then you can execute the script by entering the path in terminal. (if your script depends on relative path, make sure to `cd` to the parent directory of the script before running it)

Note: This will permit any user to execute the script (without any authentication)

***Another way is to add the non-sudo user into a group which has permission to execute the script:***

In this case, permissions like:

```
chmod ug+rwx,o-x+r script
#read write xecute permission to user and group and readonly to others
```

and

```
chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o-x+r
#read write xecute to user and rx to group and readonly to others
```

and so on where group have the right to execute the file will do the trick. It's more secure than using a `755` permission.

**The steps to go through with this process:**

1.Log in to the user account which has sudo privillege.

2.Change permission of the script as only user and group will be permitted to execute the script.

Example:

```
chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o-x path/to/the/script
```

3.Add the non-sudo user to the current user group:

```
sudo usermod -g $USER non_sudo_user_name
#you don't need to edit $USER, only non_sudo_user_name
```

4.Do a new login in the non sudo user account.

Now you can execute the script by running:

```
/path/to/the/script
```

Note: If your script depends on relative path, then you might need to `cd` to the parent directory of the script before running it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: are you passing tux as the user or other? if other it won't work.

Comment: If you have a group that have permission to run tux's script, you can use that group to run the script.

Comment: Thank you again, but it still did not work as I like it to. It works when I am logged in as an user with root rights. I'd like to execute the other users script without sudo, by passing a password. If this is even possible.

Comment: If your user can't use sudo, then I don't think there's any way you could provide password and execute that script. The only way I know of is to give permission to execute the script explicitly. You can simply add the sudo user to non sudo user as a group. In that way you will be able t o execute the script withou sudo and without passwords

Comment: @th1nk, edited and given a detailed process of executing it without password but with enough security margin. hope it helps you...

Comment: Good Sir, thank you very much. It's still not what I am looking for but it would probably be a workaround for others.
I don't have the possiblity to change the rights or the ownership of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your user `tux` to `/etc/sudoers` with `NOPASSWD` to allow it to run `sudo` without password prompt.

E.g. add this to the end of `/etc/sudoers` to allow elevated execution of any command without password (note, there's a special tool for that - `visudo`):

```
tux    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:  ALL
```

Or, a more restricted way - only allow this for your script:

```
tux    ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

After that check that the changes are in effect by running any command from terminal, e.g.:

```
sudo id
```

and it should not prompt for root password.

**UPDATE:**

To make Apache run a script that belongs to another user (e.g. `tux`) add this line to `sudoers`:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

Then you should be able to run it without password like so:

```
sudo -u tux /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

Also, check these:

- [How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo)
- [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/157272/allow-apache-to-run-a-command-as-a-different-user

Comment: The idea is good, I didn't have it, thank you. But there are still some issues with it:
If I give permission to execute everything this will lead to security issues. If I only allow to execute the script I have problems with dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure about the dependencies and I'd better run an experiment with just allowing ```shutdown.sh``` and see if any dependencies inherit its privileges. Unfortunately I don't have a shell with root access under my hands at the moment to test this.

Comment: The problem is, that the shutdown-script, which shuts down the webserver, need to have access to the logfiles. They have been created before by the user who is owner of the script.
I tried to allow access to these files, sadly no success. 
Best would be to really execute the script as tux by passing a password!

Comment: When you run a command with sudo without specifying a user, you run it as root. Thus you should have access to everything. ```NOPASSWD``` simply disables the password prompt you usually get in this case.

Comment: I think you got me wrong on this one. I want to be able to execute the script as a non-root user!
Otherwhise things would be clear :)

Comment: Thank you very much good Sir. It's a workaround that works in my case (the update). I am still trying to find a nice non-workaround-way for the job. This means to do a login and pass a password with the login. Sadly, it dosn't look like this will work with ssh or su. Sudo and sshpass are no options.
If I don't find another way, of course, I'll accept your answer, since it is the closest I've gotten to what I asked for, so far.