# Shell Entering the password with the command

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have a PHP script and it runs a certain command. I need my PHP script to execute commands to create a user FTP. And so I came across such a problem: I create the user's login for the password and here's the problem, I write a new password and try it out. Can I somehow execute the command immediately without input.

*Example: # passwd user password*

Comment: Example: # passwd `user` `password`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo in php exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173201/608639), [How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3166123/608639), [Execute Script as another user whilst not being root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29969560/608639), etc.