# How to execute python script from php?

Tags: php, python, html

I'm new to `php` and `html` (internet languages in general) and I would like to execute a `python` script that takes a picture from my php page.

I did some research, edited some code (according to my understanding) and came up with this, but it doens't do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="sub" value="call">Click</button>
        </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
        exec('sudo python take_picture.py');
        echo "Picture captured";
}
?>
```

I managed to execute the `python` script from a `html` page invoking a simple `php` script separately, but when it takes the picture it sends me to a new page (blank page with the text displayed) which I don't want. Here are the codes:

HTML button:

```
<form action="take_picture.php" method="post">
<button>Click</button>
</form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
exec('sudo python take_picture.py');
?>
```

What I need is to simply press the "click" button and take the picture without sending me to anywhere else.

Could you please guys aid me to achieve what I need and explain with apples what I was doing wrong or what I missed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166123/how-to-call-shell-script-from-php-that-requires-sudo)

Comment: Nope, It is not because I actually achieved this just need to do it in a different way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an :

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

More information on this Stack Overflow Question.

[Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php)

Comment: Thank you, let me check it out